# Reading csv files with async await functions in node.js. Undefined due to execution before promises resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm reading files with Node in a 4 step process. Each step has to wait for the resolution of the function it calls. It seems like a very simple task to accomplish, but the async functions are not awaiting the result of their variable definitions ( i.e. even though the variable 'finish' is dependent on the variable processData which is awaiting an async function, it fires anyway.

I'm guessing I have a butchered understanding of the fundamental behavior if my conclusions aren't correct. And I know there are a ton of threads with this issue, but I would appreciate some help. Oh, and if I log the results from the fs.readFile method in its callback, the data shows up. But the data is returned undefined from that block. Code below:

```
async function formatData(){ 
    const processData = await getFiles()
    const finish = await printData(processData)
}


async function getFiles(){
    const checkFile = await getFileData('./csvs/checkfile_for_node_test.csv')
    const scheduleFile = await getFileData('./csvs/schedules_for_node_test.csv')

    console.log('returning files')
    return {checks: checkFile, schedules: schedFile}
}

async function getFileData(file){
     const fileData = await fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => data ) 
     console.log(`file data: ${fileData}`)
     return fileData
}

function printData(data){
    console.log(data)
    return data
}

formatData()
```

Comment: You are running ``await`` on ``printData`` which is not an ``async`` function. Please make it async and check. You can also simply remove async from printData call.

Comment: Are you using a [Promisified version](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) of `readFile`?  It doesn't look that way, in which case `await fs.readFile(...)` won't do what you hope.

Comment: So you're getting `file data: undefined` in your logs, right?

Comment: That's right. User below solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are missing promise from getFileData function.  Below is the modified code

```
const fs = require("fs");

async function formatData() {
  const processData = await getFiles();
  const finish = await printData(processData);

  console.log(finish);
}

async function getFiles() {
  const checkFile = await getFileData("./hello.txt");
  const scheduleFile = await getFileData("./world.txt");

  console.log("returning files");
  return { checks: checkFile, schedules: scheduleFile };
}

async function getFileData(file) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
      if (err) rej(err);
      console.log(`file data: ${data}`);
      res({ fileData: data });
    });
  });

  return fileData;
}

async function printData(data) {
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}

formatData();
```

Comment: Don't forget to put the `resolve()` call in an `else` statement

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi, I have only renamed the resolve to res, in above code. Is it still incorrect?

Comment: No, it's not correct. You're still calling the `console.log` and the `res` even if there was an error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the code you provided is the actual code, but there seems to be a lot of issues. I will break down them one by one for you:

1. When you are calling `formatData` you should use `await` keyword before it because it is an `async` method.
2. At the last line of `getFiles` method, you mistakenly placed `schedFile` instead of `scheduleFile`.
3. You are trying to use `fs.readFile` with await. It does not work that way. You have to either promisify it or use `readFileSync`.

All put together in code:

```
async function formatData(){ 
    const processData = await getFiles()
    const finish = await printData(processData)
}


async function getFiles(){
    const checkFile = await getFileData('./csvs/checkfile_for_node_test.csv')
    const scheduleFile = await getFileData('./csvs/schedules_for_node_test.csv')

    console.log('returning files')
    return {checks: checkFile, schedules: scheduleFile}
}

async function getFileData(file){
     const readFileAsync = promisify(fs.readFile); 
     const fileData = await readFileAsync(file, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
     console.log(`file data: ${fileData}`)
     return fileData
}

function printData(data){
    console.log(data)
    return data
}

window.addEventListener('load', async function () {
   await formatData();
});
```

I hope it works.

Comment: 4. `printData` is synchronous, there's no reason to `await` the call

Comment: "*When you are calling `formatData` you should use `await` keyword*" - not necessarily, it appears to be the top-level call. What's more important is to handle errors from it, using e.g. `formatData().catch(console.error)`. Btw, this is node.js code, which doesn't have a `window` and there are no `load` events to listen for.